# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

I'm trying to fix this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from time import sleep, time
from math import sqrt
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800
window = Tk()
window.title('Bubble Blaster')
c = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='darkblue')
c.pack()
ship_id = c.create_polygon(5, 5, 5, 25, 30, 15, fill='red')
ship_id2 = c.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, outline='red')
SHIP_R = 15
MID_X = WIDTH / 2
MID_Y = HEIGHT / 2
c.move(ship_id, MID_X, MID_Y)
c.move(ship_id2, MID_X, MID_Y)
SHIP_SPD = 10
def move_ship(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        c.move(ship_id, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
        c.move(ship_id2, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
elif event.keysym == 'Down':
    c.move(ship_id, 0, SHIP_SPD)
    c.move(ship_id2, 0, SHIP_SPD)
elif event.keysym == 'Left':
    c.move(ship_id, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
    c.move(ship_id2, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
elif event.keysym == 'Right':
    c.move(ship_id, SHIP_SPD, 0)
    c.move(ship_id2, SHIP_SPD, 0)
c.bind_all('<Key>', move_ship)
bub_id = list()
bub_r = list()
bub_speed = list()
MIN_BUB_R = 10
MAX_BUB_R = 30
MAX_BUB_SPD = 10
GAP = 100
def create_bubble():
    x = WIDTH + GAP
    y = randint(0, HEIGHT)
    r = randint(MIN_BUB_R, MAX_BUB_R)
    id1 = c.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r, outline='white')
    bub_id.append(id1)
    bub_r.append(r)
    bub_speed.append(randint(1, MAX_BUB_SPD))
    `enter code here`def move_bubbles():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)):
        c.move(bub_id[i], -bub_speed[i], 0)
def get_coords(id_num):
    pos = c.coords(id_num)
    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
    y = (pos[1] + pos[3])/2
    return x, y
def del_bubble(i):
    del bub_r[i]
    del bub_speed[i]
    c.delete(bub_id[i])
    del bub_id[i]
def clean_up_bubs():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        x, y = get_coords(bub_id[i])
        if x < -GAP:
            del_bubble(i)
def distance(id1, id2):
    x1, y1 = get_coords(id1)
    x2, y2 = get_coords(id2)
    return sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
def collision():
    points = 0
    for bub in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        if distance(ship_id2, bub_id[bub]) < (SHIP_R + bub_r[bub]):
            points += (bub_r[bub] + bub_speed[bub])
            del_bubble(bub)
        return points
c.create_text(50, 30, text='TIME', fill='white')
c.create_text(150, 30, text='SCORE', fill='white')
time_text = c.create_text(50, 50, fill='white')
score_text = c.create_text(150, 50, fill='white')
def show_score(score):
    c.itemconfig(score_text, text=str(score))
def show_time(time_left):
    c.itemconfig(time_text, text=str(time_left))
BUB_CHANCE  = 10
TIME_LIMIT = 30
BONUS_SCORE = 1000
score = 0
bonus = 0
end = time() + TIME_LIMIT
#MAIN GAME LOOP
while time() < end:
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_bubble()
    move_bubbles()
    clean_up_bubs()
    score = score + collision()
    if (int(score / BONUS_SCORE)) > bonus:
        bonus += 1
        end += TIME_LIMIT
    show_score(score)
    show_time(int(end - time()))
    window.update()
    sleep(0.01)
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y, \
              text='GAME OVER', fill='white', font=('Helvietica', 30))
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y + 30, \
              text='Score: '+ str(score), fill='white')
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y + 45, \
              text='Bonus time: '+ str(bonus*TIME_LIMIT), fill='white')
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Bubble Blaster.py", line 97, in <module>
    score = score + collision()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I have figured out what it means; it means that one of the variables isn't an integer. I don't know how to fix it. I think the main problem area is:

```
def collision():
        points = 0
        for bub in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
            if distance(ship_id2, bub_id[bub]) < (SHIP_R + bub_r[bub]):
                points += (bub_r[bub] + bub_speed[bub])
                del_bubble(bub)
            return points
```

my version of python is 3.4.1.

Answer (score 2):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Bubble Blaster.py", line 97, in 
    score = score + collision()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Now, `NoneType` is the type of the `None` object. So, the error indicates that `collision()` returned `None`. Let's look at its implementation.

```
def collision():
    points = 0
    for bub in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        if distance(ship_id2, bub_id[bub]) < (SHIP_R + bub_r[bub]):
            points += (bub_r[bub] + bub_speed[bub])
            del_bubble(bub)
        return points
```

If the `return` statement had executed, then an `int` would have been returned. If a function terminates without encountering a `return` statement, the function implicitly returns `None`. That must be what has happened here. And that can only happen if the for loop has not been entered.

I've not attempted to suggest a fix for the problem, only to diagnose its cause.

Comment: It's worth mentioning for the python novice that functions have an implicit `None` returned when the execution finds the end of scope without an explicit `return`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I changed

```
def collision():
    points = 0
    for bub in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        if distance(ship_id2, bub_id[bub]) < (SHIP_R + bub_r[bub]):
            points += (bub_r[bub] + bub_speed[bub])
            del_bubble(bub)
         return points
```

to

```
def collision():
        points = 0
        for bub in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
            if distance(ship_id2, bub_id[bub]) < (SHIP_R + bub_r[bub]):
                points += (bub_r[bub] + bub_speed[bub])
                del_bubble(bub)
        return points
```

and now it works!